# pdfpages doesn't work, error: file not found

Tags: latex, pdfpages

I do have a problem with the "pdfpages" package. I would like to insert a pdf drawing in my appendix. The file I would like to insert is in the same folder, the name of the file in my code is correct, nevertheless the error "cannot find file 'Bild100.pdf'" is displayed again and again.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, fleqn]{report}
                    
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}                                                   
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}         
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\usepackage{adjustbox}                              
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[style=numeric, sorting=none]{biblatex}  
\addbibresource{Quellen.bib}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {,}}
\newcommand{\RM}[1]{\MakeUppercase{\romannumeral #1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\centering
    {\scshape\LARGE\textbf{Studienarbeit im Fach BlaBla Sommersemester 2022} \par}                                  %Titel der Arbeit
    \vspace{1cm}
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{Titelbild}\par\vspace{1cm}
    {\scshape\Large BlaBla\par}                     %Fach 
    {\scshape \Large Sommersemester 2022\par}               %Semester
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    {\scshape Betreuer: Porf. Dr.-Ing. BlaBla\par}      %Betreuer/Dozent

    
    {\scshape\today\par}                                                                    %Aktuelles Datum
\end{titlepage}


\include{AnhangA}


\end{document}
```

Appendix

```
\chapter{Anhang}

\includepdf[pages={-}]{Bild100.pdf}
```

I'm using an M1 MacBook Pro and Texpad.
I have no idea what I am doing wrong and would appreciate any help!

.log File

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (MiKTeX 21.8) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.5.6)  6 MAY 2022 10:49
entering extended mode
**"./Studienarbeit Gruppe 06.tex"
(Studienarbeit Gruppe 06.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-04-29> (VTreport.cls
Document Class: VTreport 2016/08/09
Report-Class für Abschlussarbeiten in der Fak. VT. Last Modified 09.08.2016 at
 VT by Armin Beier
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\fix-cm.sty
Package: fix-cm 2020/11/24 v1.1t fixes to LaTeX

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\ts1enc.def
File: ts1enc.def 2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding TS1 on input line 47.
))
(C:\Users\scharoldso83541\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrr
eprt.cls
Document Class: scrreprt 2021/11/13 v3.35 KOMA-Script document class (report)

(C:\Users\scharoldso83541\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrk
base.sty
Package: scrkbase 2021/11/13 v3.35 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent b
asics and keyval usage)

(C:\Users\scharoldso83541\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrb
ase.sty
Package: scrbase 2021/11/13 v3.35 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent 
basics and keyval usage)

(C:\Users\scharoldso83541\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrl
file.sty
Package: scrlfile 2021/11/13 v3.35 KOMA-Script package (file load hooks)

(C:\Users\scharoldso83541\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrl
file-hook-3.34.sty
Package: scrlfile-hook-3.34 2021/11/13 v3.35 KOMA-Script package (using LaTeX h
ooks)

(C:\Users\scharoldso83541\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrl
ogo.sty
Package: scrlogo 2021/11/13 v3.35 KOMA-Script package (logo)
))) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
)
Applying: [2021/05/01] Usage of raw or classic option list on input line 252.
Already applied: [0000/00/00] Usage of raw or classic option list on input line
 368.
))
(C:\Users\scharoldso83541\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\tocb
asic.sty
Package: tocbasic 2021/11/13 v3.35 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
\scr@dte@tocline@numberwidth=\skip47
\scr@dte@tocline@numbox=\box50
)
Package tocbasic Info: babel extension for `toc' omitted
(tocbasic)             because of missing \bbl@set@language on input line 137.


Class scrreprt Warning: You've used obsolete option `pointlessnumbers'.
(scrreprt)              Usage of this option indicates an old document
(scrreprt)              and changes compatibility level using
(scrreprt)              `numbers=noenddot,version=first,
(scrreprt)              enabledeprecatedfontcommands' that may result
(scrreprt)              in further warnings.
(scrreprt)              If you don't want this, you should simply
(scrreprt)              replace option `pointlessnumbers' by `numbers=noenddot'
.

Class scrreprt Info: Switching compatibility level to `first'.

Class scrreprt Warning: deprecated option `enabledeprecatedfontcommands'.
(scrreprt)              Note, that this option was already depreacted when
(scrreprt)              it has been defined. Support for old font commands
(scrreprt)              has been removed from KOMA-Script more than one
(scrreprt)              decade ago. It is not recommended to use them any
(scrreprt)              longer. Therefore usage of this class option also
(scrreprt)              is not recommended.

Class scrreprt Info: File `scrsize12pt.clo' used to setup font sizes on input l
ine 2487.

(C:\Users\scharoldso83541\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrs
ize12pt.clo
File: scrsize12pt.clo 2021/11/13 v3.35 KOMA-Script font size class option (12pt
)
)
(C:\Users\scharoldso83541\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\type
area.sty
Package: typearea 2021/11/13 v3.35 KOMA-Script package (type area)
\ta@bcor=\skip48
\ta@div=\count184
\ta@hblk=\skip49
\ta@vblk=\skip50
\ta@temp=\skip51
\footheight=\skip52
Package typearea Info: These are the values describing the layout:
(typearea)             DIV  = 12
(typearea)             BCOR = 0.0pt
(typearea)             \paperwidth      = 597.50793pt
(typearea)              \textwidth      = 448.13095pt
(typearea)              DIV departure   = -6%
(typearea)              \evensidemargin = 2.4185pt
(typearea)              \oddsidemargin  = 2.4185pt
(typearea)             \paperheight     = 845.04694pt
(typearea)              \textheight     = 635.5pt
(typearea)              \topmargin      = -41.72441pt
(typearea)              \headheight     = 18.125pt
(typearea)              \headsep        = 21.75pt
(typearea)              \topskip        = 12.0pt
(typearea)              \footskip       = 50.75pt
(typearea)              \baselineskip   = 14.5pt
(typearea)              on input line 1743.
)
\c@part=\count185
\c@chapter=\count186
\c@section=\count187
\c@subsection=\count188
\c@subsubsection=\count189
\c@paragraph=\count190
\c@subparagraph=\count191
\scr@dte@chapter@maxnumwidth=\skip53
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\chapter on input line 5717.
\scr@dte@section@maxnumwidth=\skip54
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\section on input line 5728.
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\section on input line 5728.
\scr@dte@part@maxnumwidth=\skip55
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=true'
(scrreprt)           for `\part on input line 5737.
\scr@dte@subsection@maxnumwidth=\skip56
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\subsection on input line 5747.
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\subsection on input line 5747.
\scr@dte@subsubsection@maxnumwidth=\skip57
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\subsubsection on input line 5757.
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\subsubsection on input line 5757.
\scr@dte@paragraph@maxnumwidth=\skip58
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\paragraph on input line 5768.
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\paragraph on input line 5768.
\scr@dte@subparagraph@maxnumwidth=\skip59
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\subparagraph on input line 5778.
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\subparagraph on input line 5778.
\abovecaptionskip=\skip60
\belowcaptionskip=\skip61
\c@pti@nb@sid@b@x=\box51
Package tocbasic Info: babel extension for `lof' omitted
(tocbasic)             because of missing \bbl@set@language on input line 6958.

\scr@dte@figure@maxnumwidth=\skip62
\c@figure=\count192
Package tocbasic Info: babel extension for `lot' omitted
(tocbasic)             because of missing \bbl@set@language on input line 6974.

\scr@dte@table@maxnumwidth=\skip63
\c@table=\count193
Class scrreprt Info: Using old \@makefntext due to compatibility level
(scrreprt)           less than 3.22 on input line 7129.
Class scrreprt Info: Redefining `\numberline' on input line 7142.
\bibindent=\dimen138
) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2021/02/14 v1.3d Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks17
\inpenc@posthook=\toks18
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2021/04/29 v2.0v Standard LaTeX package
)
(C:\Users\scharoldso83541\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrl
ayer-scrpage.sty
Package: scrlayer-scrpage 2021/11/13 v3.35 KOMA-Script package (end user interf
ace for scrlayer)

(C:\Users\scharoldso83541\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrl
ayer.sty
Package: scrlayer 2021/11/13 v3.35 KOMA-Script package (defining layers and pag
e styles)
Package scrlayer Info: Using already defined \footheight
(scrlayer)             hoping, that this is a length and
(scrlayer)             not only a macro on input line 136.
Package scrlayer Info: patching LaTeX kernel macro \pagestyle on input line 216
2.
)
Package scrlayer-scrpage Info: Makeing stand-alone element `pagehead' from
(scrlayer-scrpage)             alias to `pageheadfoot' on input line 1085.
Package scrlayer-scrpage Info: deactivating warning for font element
(scrlayer-scrpage)             `pagefoot' on input line 1109.
)
Package scrlayer-scrpage Info: auto-selection of `pagestyleset=KOMA-Script'.
 (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2020/11/24 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/babel\babel.sty
Package: babel 2021/07/22 3.63 The Babel package

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/babel\babel.def
File: babel.def 2021/07/22 3.63 Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count194
\U@D=\dimen139
\l@unhyphenated=\language83

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/babel\txtbabel.def)
\bbl@readstream=\read2
)
\bbl@dirlevel=\count195

*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*

(C:\Users\scharoldso83541\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/arabi\bblopts.cf
g
File: bblopts.cfg 2005/09/08 v0.1 add Arabic and Farsi to "declared" options of
 babel
) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/babel-german\ngerman.ldf
Language: ngerman 2021/02/27 v2.13 German support for babel (post-1996 orthogra
phy)

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/babel-german\ngermanb.ldf
Language: ngermanb 2021/02/27 v2.13 German support for babel (post-1996 orthogr
aphy)
Package babel Info: Making " an active character on input line 122.
)))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2021/04/20 v2.17j AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip64

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks19
\ex@=\dimen140
))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen141
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count196
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 234.
\uproot@=\count197
\leftroot@=\count198
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 399.
\classnum@=\count199
\DOTSCASE@=\count266
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 496.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 499.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 620.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box52
\strutbox@=\box53
\big@size=\dimen142
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 743.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 744.
\macc@depth=\count267
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count268
\dotsspace@=\muskip16
\c@parentequation=\count269
\dspbrk@lvl=\count270
\tag@help=\toks20
\row@=\count271
\column@=\count272
\maxfields@=\count273
\andhelp@=\toks21
\eqnshift@=\dimen143
\alignsep@=\dimen144
\tagshift@=\dimen145
\tagwidth@=\dimen146
\totwidth@=\dimen147
\lineht@=\dimen148
\@envbody=\toks22
\multlinegap=\skip65
\multlinetaggap=\skip66
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks23
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2923.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2924.
)
(C:\Users\scharoldso83541\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/siunitx\siunitx.
sty
Package: siunitx 2022-05-03 v3.1.1 A comprehensive (SI) units package
\l__siunitx_angle_tmp_dim=\dimen149
\l__siunitx_angle_marker_box=\box54
\l__siunitx_angle_unit_box=\box55
\l__siunitx_compound_count_int=\count274

(C:\Users\scharoldso83541\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/translations\tra
nslations.sty
Package: translations 2022/02/05 v1.12 internationalization of LaTeX2e packages
 (CN)

(C:\Users\scharoldso83541\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/etoolbox\etoolbo
x.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count275
)
(C:\Users\scharoldso83541\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pdftexcmds\pdf
texcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(C:\Users\scharoldso83541\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/infwarerr\infw
arerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(C:\Users\scharoldso83541\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.st
y
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
)
(C:\Users\scharoldso83541\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/ltxcmds\ltxcmd
s.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
))
\l__siunitx_number_exponent_fixed_int=\count276
\l__siunitx_number_min_decimal_int=\count277
\l__siunitx_number_min_integer_int=\count278
\l__siunitx_number_round_precision_int=\count279
\l__siunitx_number_group_first_int=\count280
\l__siunitx_number_group_size_int=\count281
\l__siunitx_number_group_minimum_int=\count282
\l__siunitx_table_tmp_box=\box56
\l__siunitx_table_tmp_dim=\dimen150
\l__siunitx_table_column_width_dim=\dimen151
\l__siunitx_table_integer_box=\box57
\l__siunitx_table_decimal_box=\box58
\l__siunitx_table_before_box=\box59
\l__siunitx_table_after_box=\box60
\l__siunitx_table_before_dim=\dimen152
\l__siunitx_table_carry_dim=\dimen153
\l__siunitx_unit_tmp_int=\count283
\l__siunitx_unit_position_int=\count284
\l__siunitx_unit_total_int=\count285

(C:\Users\scharoldso83541\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/l3packages/l3key
s2e\l3keys2e.sty
(C:\Users\scharoldso83541\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.s
ty
Package: expl3 2022-04-29 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(C:\Users\scharoldso83541\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/l3backend\l3back
end-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2022-04-20 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count286
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box61
))
Package: l3keys2e 2022-01-12 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
)

! LaTeX Error: File `array.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 
         
l.8319 \cs_new_protected:Npn
                             \__siunitx_declare_column:Nnn #1#2#3 
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)

 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 10353 strings out of 478819
 256910 string characters out of 2855371
 667634 words of memory out of 3000000
 28272 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 470321 words of font info for 30 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 122i,1n,122p,10675b,270s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: You're example works fine for me. Can you show the .log file so we can check which engine etc. you use?

Comment: Hi @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, the text in the .log file is extremely long and I see now option to attach a file in the comments. Could you tell me if there is a workaround or something? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You could try if you can add it to your question in a codeblock. If it is too long, you could share it via github.com , https://pastebin.com/ or similar sites

Comment: I uploaded the file in my dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wev2a37a35og4hx/texpad-error-log.txt?dl=0

Comment: Thanks! No idea what's going on there, but that does not look anything like a tex log file. No idea what your texpad thingy might be doing. Can you try to compile manually? Open a terminal, go to the folder of your .tex file and do `pdflatex your_filename`

Comment: Sorry, I think I just found the correct file? I added it to my question!

Comment: Ok, that looks more like a log file. The first error it reports is `! LaTeX Error: File `array.sty' not found.` You have to fix this first.

Comment: I added the new .log file in the question. When compile the Document without the ```\includepdf[pages={-}]{Bild100.pdf}``` it runs without a error. When I add the ```\includepdf[pages={-}]{Bild100.pdf}``` the error arises.